# Why do I need to define a trait to define an implementation on an external type?

Tags: rust

The `std::iter` library has an [AdditiveIter trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.AdditiveIterator.html) which only ever has a single `impl`:

```
pub trait AdditiveIterator<A> {
  fn sum(&mut self) -> A;
}

impl<A: Add<A, A> + Zero, T: Iterator<A>> AdditiveIterator<A> for T {
  fn sum(&mut self) -> A {
      let zero: A = Zero::zero();
      self.fold(zero, |s, x| s + x)
  }
}
```

This trait exists so that we can write `foo.iter().sum()`. If we were happy with writing `sum(foo.iter())` instead, then the above code could be written more simply as:

```
fn sum<A: Add<A, A> + Zero, T: Iterator<A>>(iter: &mut T) -> A {
    let zero: A = Zero::zero();
    iter.fold(zero, |s, x| s + x)
}
```

Is there a way to get the best of both? Can I write `sum` so that:

- I can use `foo.iter().sum()` syntax; and
- I don't have to duplicate the `fn sum(&mut self) -> A` type signature?

Comment: UFCS, when it comes, will help a lot with this.

Answer (score 0):

`Iterator` is not a type, it's actually a trait. If it was a type then this would be possible, something like:

```
impl<A: Add<A, A> + Zero> Iterator<A> {
  fn sum(&mut self) -> A {
      let zero: A = Zero::zero();
      self.fold(zero, |s, x| s + x)
  }
}
```

If we could implement methods on a generic type we could do:

```
impl<A: Add<A, A> + Zero, T: Iterator<A>> T {
  fn sum(&mut self) -> A {
      let zero: A = Zero::zero();
      self.fold(zero, |s, x| s + x)
  }
}
```

But the compiler doesn't like that, and forces us to define a new trait.

Comment: Why doesn't the Rust compiler allow the second form you described?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think it may have to do with how it keeps track of method implementations.